# What are these grub in my flowerbed?

Tags: identification, pests

I discovered a large number of these grubs in my flowerbed. These critters are in Basingstoke, Hampshire in the south of England.

Should I be concerned? Can anybody identify these?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

Managed an ID based upon your hints. It's a *Merodon equestris* larvae. Commonly known as the Large Narcissus fly.

It's a bulb pest but I'm not sure I mind.

The image that lead to the ID is [here](http://www.bugsandweeds.co.uk/hoverflies.html).